# Setting the classpath of CTAKES_HOME/lib in setenv.sh file in bin folder in tomcat giving issues

Tags: ctakes

I am trying to upgrade Java and Tomcat server for a rest api that hits CTAKES YTEX. The current version of Java is 1.7, Tomcat is 7 and CTAKES Ytex is 3.2. Trying to upgrade JAVA to 1.8, Tomcat to 9 and CTAKES YTEX to 4.

While setting classpath of CTAKES lib folder in setenv.sh file in bin folder of tomcat,I am getting following error in Tomcat.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;Lorg/apache/jasper/runtime/ProtectedFunctionMapper;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:139)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

It was working fine with CTAKES 3.2.

Changed  the tomcat versions between 8 and 9. Switched the OS between mac and linux.